# IsNumeric in Open Office Basic or VBA

Tags: vba, openoffice-basic

Is there a function that tests for a string (non numeric) values and returns a boolean value in Open Office Basic?

I tried IsNumeric on a string and it returns a boolean False.  But when I negate it with Not(IsNumeric(value)), it converts the return value to a long or an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Open Office Basic, you can use [`ISNUMBER()`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_ISNUMBER_function)

```
ISNUMBER(123)
```

> returns TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent hours trying to work out what was up with the ISNUMERIC ...

```
if IsNumeric(oSheet.GetCellByPosition( 8,iRow).String) then
    oSheet.GetCellByPosition(20,iRow).Value = oSheet.GetCellByPosition( 8,iRow).Value()
else
    oSheet.GetCellByPosition(20,iRow).String = oSheet.GetCellByPosition( 8,iRow).String()
endif
```

The problem was the fact that attribute feeding into the IsNumeric function must be a string ( **not** an object or a numeric! )

I will be contacting Andrew Pitonak to ask him to makes this clearer in his manuals.